# Joint CDF of independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

I know that The joint cumulative function of two random variables X and Y is defined as:

$F_{XY}(x,y)=P(X≤x,Y≤y)$.

How can I find the CDF is $x=y$. In other words is what will be $Pr\{min(X,Y)<x\}$ where $x=y$.

If I already know the individual CDF of both $X$ and $Y$ i.e.  $F_{X}(x)$ and  $F_{Y}(x)$, can they be useful to compute the $Pr\{min(X,Y)<x\}$?

Any kind of help will be very much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: $$\Pr(X\leqslant x,Y\leqslant x)=\Pr(\max(X,Y)\leqslant x)\ne\Pr(\min(X,Y)\leqslant x)$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
\Pr(\min(X, Y) \leq x) &= \Pr(X \leq x \ \lor\ Y \leq x) \\
&= \Pr(X \leq x) + \Pr(Y \leq x) - \Pr(X \leq x \ \land\ Y \leq x) \\
&= F_X(x) + F_Y(x) - F_{X,Y}(x, x)
\end{align}

Comment: Thak you for your help. One more thing, how to find $F_{X,Y}(x,x)$?

Comment: @BaidalKocham If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $$F_{X,Y}(x, x) = F_X(x) \cdot F_Y(x)$$